# Are eigenvalues of sum of two matrices equal to sum of other two matrices with identical eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider I want the eigenvalues of $C=AA^T+BB^T$. How can I prove that the ***non-zero*** eigenvalues of $C$ is equal to matrix $D$ in which $D=A^TA+B^TB$?

If not possible in general, $A$ and $B$ are i.i.d Gaussain matrices.

I know this claim is true as I simulated it in Matlab.

*EDIT: I also Assume that C has no Zero eigenvalues*

Comment: "I know this claim is true as I simulated it in matlab": first of all, experiments don't qualify as proofs.  Second, are you trying to prove that it's true for all matrices, or that it occurs with $100\%$ probability?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I understand that simulations are not reliable, but in my case they work. I just want to show using one is equal to use the other one to proceed. The general case is not important if it is hard, just the Gaussian case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. E.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},
$$
$$
C=AA^T+BB^T=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&0},\ D=A^TA+B^TB=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1}.
$$
The only nonzero eigenvalue of $C$ is $2$ and it is not an eigenvalues of $D$.

It is true, however, that when all entries of $A$ and $B$ are i.i.d. $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, we have
$$
\mathbb E(C)=\mathbb E(D)=2n(\sigma^2I_n+\mu^2E)
$$
where $E$ is the all-one matrix.

Comment: I want to work with the trace of inverse of their sum, i.e. $D^{-1}$. The point is that in my case, D is not a Wishart Matrix, but C is.

Comment: I also Assume that C has no Zero eigenvalues. Sorry that I didn't mention that in the Question. It is edited now.

Comment: @MasoudArash Whether $C$ has a zero eigenvalue is unimportant. If you perturb the $A$ and $B$ in my answer by a small $\epsilon I$, you will still get a counterexample, but $C$ and $D$ are positive definite in this case.